# quotient by contractible space and homotopy equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a space and $L$ be a subspace of $X$ that is contractible. Then is $X/L$ homotopy-equivalent to $X$ itself? it doesn't seem trivial to me at al...If so, how to show it rigorously? Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is shown at the very start of Hatcher. Chapter 0, page 11.

Comment: You would probably want $(L,X)$ to satisfy the homotopy extension property.

Comment: You would **certainly** want $(L,X)$ to satisfy some conditions, of which the HEP is the usual one. The result is a special case of the gluing theorem for homotopy equivalences: see this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96071/general-gluing-theorem-for-adjunction-spaces

Comment: As an example of where this is not true. Take $X=S^1$ and for some point $x\in X$, let $L=X\setminus\{x\}$. The space $X/L$ here is the [Sierpinski space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) which is contractible, so not homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.